# CSS3 keyframe animation background image not changing in IE

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

So i have a a element whose border and background image change (image color corresponds with the border color) it all works fine but not in IE 10+ only the border color changes what am i missing?

```
.circleGreen:before {
    border: 4px solid;
    background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto auto;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 12s infinite;
    -moz-animation: mymove 12s infinite;
    -ms-animation: mymove 12s infinite;
    -o-animation: mymove 12s infinite;
    animation: mymove 12s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
    25%  {border: 4px solid #f7ba44; background: url(img/adapts3.png) no-repeat center center;}
    50%  {border: 4px solid #f6135e; background: url(img/adapts2.png) no-repeat center center;}
    75% {border: 4px solid #2ccafe; background: url(img/adapts4.png) no-repeat center center;}
    100%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
}
@-moz-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
    25%  {border: 4px solid #f7ba44; background: url(img/adapts3.png) no-repeat center center;}
    50%  {border: 4px solid #f6135e; background: url(img/adapts2.png) no-repeat center center;}
    75% {border: 4px solid #2ccafe; background: url(img/adapts4.png) no-repeat center center;}
    100%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
}
@-ms-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
    25%  {border: 4px solid #f7ba44; background: url(img/adapts3.png) no-repeat center center;}
    50%  {border: 4px solid #f6135e; background: url(img/adapts2.png) no-repeat center center;}
    75% {border: 4px solid #2ccafe; background: url(img/adapts4.png) no-repeat center center;}
    100%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
}
@-o-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
    25%  {border: 4px solid #f7ba44; background: url(img/adapts3.png) no-repeat center center;}
    50%  {border: 4px solid #f6135e; background: url(img/adapts2.png) no-repeat center center;}
    75% {border: 4px solid #2ccafe; background: url(img/adapts4.png) no-repeat center center;}
    100%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
}
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
    25%  {border: 4px solid #f7ba44; background: url(img/adapts3.png) no-repeat center center;}
    50%  {border: 4px solid #f6135e; background: url(img/adapts2.png) no-repeat center center;}
    75% {border: 4px solid #2ccafe; background: url(img/adapts4.png) no-repeat center center;}
    100%   {border: 4px solid #18f6b0; background: url(img/adapts1.png) no-repeat center center;}
}
```

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle with this? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the reason is that this doesn't work is that css key frames to change background images does not work on before or after elements and this is apparently how the spec outlines it so IE is following the spec and all other browsers are not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Instead of

```
background-size: auto auto;
```

IE has an issue calculating *auto* values... You can also use all with its vendor specific case if needed, each vendor (even Chrome x FF) renders background-size differently:

```
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
   -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;    
    -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Ok, create a fiddle with your CSS and HTML then, better to think ;)

Comment: Damn... IE doesn't support keyframe animation of background images this way. Only with a sprite sheet.

Comment: IE being IE... as usual hehe.

Answer (score 0):

only chrome can support the keyframe for background image changes。
i try the sprite， but if you want the imgage window to fit the width of its father window and change its width and height dynamicly. you can just ues % to achieve it，but it will be a little shaking during the animation. i have no idea about it